# Is there a difference SMO ServerConnection transaction methods versus using the SqlConnectionObject property?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server-2005, smo

I am using SMO to create databases and tables on a SQL Server.  I want to do so in a transaction.  Are both of these methods of doing so valid and equivalent:

First method:

```
Server server;
//...
server.ConnectionContext.BeginTransaction();
//...
server.ConnectionContext.CommitTransaction();
```

Second method:

```
Server server;
// ...
SqlConnection conn = server.ConnectionContext.SqlConnectionObject;
SqlTransaction trans = conn.BeginTransaction();
// ...
trans.Commit();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two are equivalent. Using a SqlTransaction object allows you to place the transaction in an `using` scope:

```
using(SqlTransaction  trn = conn.BeginTransaction ())
{
 ...
 trn.Commit ();
}
```

This is a better pattern in presence of exceptions.