# Transactions in SMO.Server ConnectionContext not working for fatal severity

Tags: c#, sql-server, transactions, smo

```
using System;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common;

namespace ScriptRunner
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var script = File.ReadAllText("Test.sql");
            const string sqlConnectionString = @"Data Source=my\ds;
                    Initial Catalog=myic;
                    Connection Timeout=0;
                    Integrated Security=true";
            SqlConnection connection = null;
            Server server = null;
            try
            {
                connection = new SqlConnection(sqlConnectionString);
                server = new Server(new ServerConnection(connection));
                server.ConnectionContext.BeginTransaction();
                server.ConnectionContext.ExecuteNonQuery(script);
                server.ConnectionContext.CommitTransaction();
            }
            catch { server.ConnectionContext.RollBackTransaction(); }
            finally { connection?.Dispose(); }
        }
    }
}
```

The code works perfectly, except when the error is [fatal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/errors-events/database-engine-error-severities).

What I mean by fatal:
when inside the Test.sql, there is:

```
insert into TestTable (result) values ('transaction commited')
raiserror('tset', 17, -1) with log
```

it works - the transaction is rolled back, nothing new in TestTable

but when inside Test.sql is fatal raiserror (20):

```
insert into TestTable (result) values ('transaction commited')
raiserror('tset', 20, -1) with log
```

the insert is beeing commited to database, like there were no transaction.

This is the spinoff of question [How to use transactions in SMO.Server ConnectionContext](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47204709/3922292) where I had fatal error in script and thought that transactions are not working at all.

**The question:** How to make this code handle fatal errors?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the fatal error is supposed to terminate process, which terminates connection. As the XACT_ABORT was not set to ON, the behaviour was as described (weird nevertheless, I'd rather expect transaction hanging..). Setting SET XACT_ABORT ON at the begining of the script fixes the problem. References:

- [RAISEERROR to stop execution](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/483d6be7-6518-41c9-8138-aa1412ae8252/raiseerror-to-stop-execution?forum=transactsql)
- [XACT_ABORT on MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-xact-abort-transact-sql)
- https://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1442746-391-1.aspx